# What is the difference in cosmesis of the treatment of a seborrheic keratosis between cryotherapy and electrodesiccation?

Tags: dermatology, treatment, cryotherapy

There exist different treatments to remove a seborrheic keratosis (SK), such as cryotherapy and electrodesiccation {1}. I wonder what the difference in cosmesis of the treatment of a seborrheic keratosis between cryotherapy and electrodesiccation is.

I have only found one study {2}:

> Conclusion: Cryosurgery and electrodesiccation are both effective treatment modalities for truncal SKs. While cosmetic outcomes were similar, cryosurgery resulted in less postinflammatory hyperpigmentation.

However, the sample size is only 33.

Are there other, preferably larger studies comparing the difference in cosmesis of the treatment of a seborrheic keratosis between cryotherapy and electrodesiccation?

---

References:

- {1} [Cryosurgery for Common Skin Conditions](https://www.aafp.org/afp/2004/0515/p2365.html)
- {2} Ethington, Elizabeth, Andia Mitri, David Surprenant, Michael Murphy, Rebecca Rovner, Jeave Reserva, James Swan, William Adams, Rebecca Tung, and Kristin Lee. "Patient Preferences and Comparative Outcomes Regarding Cryosurgery versus Electrodesiccation in the Removal of Truncal Seborrheic Keratoses." The Journal of clinical and aesthetic dermatology 12, no. 9 (2019): E53. [Patient Preferences and Comparative Outcomes Regarding Cryosurgery versus Electrodesiccation in the Removal of Truncal Seborrheic Keratoses](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6777698/)